# Сжатие файлов перед отправкой на сервер?

Tags: сервер, gzip, минификация

Имеющиеся средства разработки на клиенте перед отправкой на сервер позволяют использовать разные способы сжатия: например через gulp, или прям из редактора и др. пр. возможности. С другой стороны есть сжатие на сервере: GZIP .htaccess с mod_deflate.
Вопрос: как взаимосвязаны методы сжатия на клиенте и на сервере, взаимосвязаны ли вообще? - то есть, например, если файлы сжаты на клиенте, нужно ли и имеет ли смысл GZIP-сжатие на сервере?

Comment: Если от клиента отправляется сжатый файл на сервер, то смысла делать сжатие на сервере я не вижу. Тоже самое и про сервер - клиент, если сжатие происходит на сервере, зачем это делать у клиента? Но как мне кажется, если есть возможность, что-то не делать на сервере, лучше этого не делать. Гуру говорят что-то типа : "не программируй всякие "штуки" на сервере, оставь его в покое(не нагружай его)"

Comment: По логике так, да. Я не силён в этом вопросе, предположил возможные подводные камни, решил уточнить.